# What is the best way to get a value from a reference table to update a foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a mapping table that maps an int to a string for example

[image]

I have another table that references this one with a foreign key relationship

```
create table products (
    product_name varchar (50),
    color_id int,
    constraint fk_products foreign key (color_id) references colors (color_id)
);
```

[image]

My question is the best way to get the color_id from the colors table when I am updating the products table - for example if I get a new product that is "red" and I want to enter that product into the product table with the color_id of 1.

The two ideas I have thought of are to

1. do a select from the colors table to get the color_id for the color "red". But I don't like the idea of needing to run a select every time I update the products table
2. hardcode the values in my code for the colors, but that seems very annoying from a maintenance perspective, because I would need to update the code every time a new color is added.

I am using postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up the values.  This is pretty easy in an insert.  Something like:

```
insert into products p
    select v.name, c.color_id
    from (values ('name1', 'red'), ('name2, 'blue')) v(name, color) join
         colors c
         on c.color = v.color;
```

If you are concerned about performance, just be sure you have an index on `colors(color)`.